# How to compute this quotient group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $a,b,c$ be three different words,how to compute the following quotient group

$$span(a,b,c)/span(a-b+c,a+b-c)$$

where $span(a,b,c)$ denote the free abelian group generated by $a,b,c$

I’ve encountered this question when I try to compute the homology groups of Klein bottle,but I have such a poor background in algebra...

Comment: You have an answer below for this case, but in general: Smith Normal Form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\langle a-b+c, a+b-c\rangle=\langle a+b-c, 2a\rangle$.

Then, $\langle a,b,c\rangle/\langle a+b-c,2a\rangle=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

To see the above intuitively, note that quotienting out is something like setting to zero, so $a+b-c=0$, implies that $c=a+b$, so $c$ is a "redundant" generator.

Then $2a=0$, will give the $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ part.

The $\mathbb{Z}$ part is due to the other generator $b$.